# Find the minimum value of $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta+\csc^2\theta+\sec^2\theta+\tan^2\theta+\cot^2 \theta$

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, maxima-minima

> What is the minimum value of this expression?
>   $$\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta+\csc^2\theta+\sec^2\theta+\tan^2\theta+\cot^2 \theta$$

I tried grouping $\sin^2x+\csc^2x$, $\cos^2x+\sec^2x$ and $\cot^2x+\tan^2x$. 
I got the answer as $6$ but the book says $7$. How?

Comment: You can minimise your three expressions separately, but they don't attain their minimum value at the same place. So the sum of the minima is less that the minimum of the sum.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065943/to-prove-sin-theta-csc-theta2-cos-theta-sec-theta2-ge-9

Answer (score 1):

Since $\tan^2\theta=\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}-1$ and $\cot^2\theta=\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}-1$, your expression it's
$$2\left(\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}+\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}\right)-1=\frac{8}{\sin^22\theta}-1\geq7.$$
The equality occurs for $\theta=45^{\circ}.$

Comment: What I have done is that I have evaluated $Cos^2x+Sec^2x$ using AM and GM and hence I got the answer as  $ 2$ .I have done the same for the other two.Hence I got $2+2+2$ which is $6$

Comment: Post please your wrong solution. I'll find a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta+\csc^2\theta+\sec^2\theta+\tan^2\theta+\cot^2\theta$$

$$=1+1+1+2(\tan^2\theta+\cot^2\theta)$$

Now  $\tan^2\theta+\cot^2\theta=(\tan\theta-\cot\theta)^2+2\ge2$