# Find the least value of $ \sec^6 x +\csc^6 x + \sec^6 x\csc^6 x$

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima

Find the least value of $$ \sec^6 x +\csc^6 x + \sec^6 x\csc^6 x$$
I tried AM greater than equal to GM
But that's for finding maximum value.  This can probably be solved with calculus but I don't know for some reason I can't find the answer . Which is $80$.

Comment: Add 1 and subtract 1 distribute the factorizable terms  trust me it will help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: use trig identities to write it in terms of $\tan\theta$. Then use the fact that the minimum value of $x + 1/x$ occurs at $x = 1$.

Comment: This hint makes the problem very simple, for sure ! $\to +1$

Answer (score 10):

Let $a=\sec^2x,b=\csc^2x\implies a+b=ab$

$$a^3+b^3+a^3b^3=(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)+a^3b^3=a^2b^2(2ab-3)$$

Now $ab=\dfrac4{\sin^22x}\ge4$

The equality occurs if $\sin^22x=1\iff\cos2x=0\iff a=b$

Comment: funny solution :-) thank you!

Comment: See also:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065943/to-prove-sin-theta-csc-theta2-cos-theta-sec-theta2-ge-9

Comment: thank you! looked interesting