# Prove that $(\sin \theta+\csc \theta)^2+(\cos\theta+\text{sec}\theta)^2\geqslant 9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

Prove that
$$
(\sin \theta+\csc \theta)^2+(\cos\theta+\text{sec}\theta)^2\geqslant 9
$$

**My attempt**: I started by expanding this and got $5+ \csc^2\theta + \sec^2\theta$, after I made this $5+ \frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}+\frac{1}{\csc^2\theta}$ but now I am not able to proceed and not getting how to prove this expression $\geq 9$.

So kindly help me.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\sin^2x}+\frac{1}{\cos^2x}=\frac{1}{\sin^2x\cos^2x}$$ can you continue?

Comment: Sorry but I am getting stucked over her only.

Comment: See [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to type mathematics on this site using MathJax and $\LaTeX$.

Comment: We can't find your error if we don't see your work.  Is the expansion you give supposed to be only the first term?  In either case it is wrong.

Comment: @RossMillikan $5+\sec^2\theta+\csc^2\theta$ looks right to me.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1065943.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for helping me and guiding me.

Answer (score 0):

Write $F=5+\csc^2 x+ \sec^2 x=7+cot^2 x+ \tan^2 x$
Thebn by AM-GM get
$$F\ge 7+2 (\cot^2 x \tan^2 x)^{1/2} =9.$$
Equalitry holds when $\tan x=\cot x \implies x=\pi/4.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: You are welcome.